# Search db Code Igniter string contained

Tags: database, codeigniter

I'm trying to do a "searcher" in code igniter and I'm new on it. I know I can do:

```
$query= $this->db->get_where('products', array('producto_nombre' => 'Arenal');
```

To get the exact coincidences. What can I do if I want to get on my query every partial coincidence, I mean, I want to get the product "Arenal" and also the product "Arenal Sound" and so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `LIKE`  instead of `WHERE`

```
$this->db->like('producto_nombre', 'Arenal', 'both');
$query = $this->db->get('products');
```

[Looking for Similar Data - codeigniter.com](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-similar-data)

Comment: Thank you so much, that was what I was looking for!